# Unable to compile SDL in linux

Tags: linux, sdl

I use the following code in the ubuntu terminal to compile my sdl code:

```
g++ SDL.cpp -o a.out -lsdl -lsdl_gfx
```

and i get this error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lsdl  
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lsdl_gfx  
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Any idea what this means?

Answer (score 0):

```
g++ SDL.cpp -I/usr/include/SDL -lSDLmain -lSDL_gfx -lSDL
```

Make sure you have SDL_gfx installed as it is a separate optional module.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will do it:

```
g++ SDL.cpp -o a.out -lSDL_gfx
```